# Complex concatenate in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues to concatenate my MySQL results the way I needed, so small help would be appreciated.

I have tree tables - posts, categories, posts_categories:

**posts:**

```
+----------+
| Field    |
+----------+
| id       |
| title    |
| body     |
| date     |
+----------+
```

**categories:**

```
+---------------+
| Field         |
+---------------+
| id            |
| category_name |
+---------------+
```

**posts_categories:**

```
+-------------+
| Field       |
+-------------+
| id          |
| post_id     |
| category_id |
+-------------+
```

My current MySQL query that gets all category names for posts:

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, categories.category_name
FROM
    posts,
    categories,
    posts_categories
WHERE
    posts_categories.category_id = categories.id
        AND posts.id = posts_categories.post_id;
```

Result of query above:

```
id       | title    | posts.category_name
 0         title1     category1
 0         title1     category3
 0         title1     category6
 1         title2     category9
```

However I'd like to concatenate category_name, so that my MySQL query results shows all category names for each post in one line. Lke this:

```
id       | title    | posts.category_name
 0         title1     category1, category3, category6
 1         title2     category9
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by your `posts` columns and use `group_concat()` to get a list of the categories

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, 
       group_concat(categories.category_name separator ', ')
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_categories ON posts.id = posts_categories.post_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON posts_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY posts.id, posts.title
```

BTW do not use the old join syntax anymore. Use the explicit JOIN sytax like in my query.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you!